# Unexplained Red X's (collisions?) with Dual-Port BRAM in Xilinx ISim

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, modelsim

I've read up on this quite a bit and I can't figure out why I would have Red X's (Collisions?) with a simple Dual-Port BRAM IP core.

[image]

I think there are only a few scenarios that can cause this:

Multiple sources: I checked and I don't have multiple sources diving current_row_data_out. I only read from it.

Simultaneous Read + WRite to the same address: Nope. As you can see in the image, read_addr and write_addr are always different.

What else can it be?

Comment: An invalid / out of range address can cause this too.

Comment: So can reading un-initialised data, if teh prior Write didn't actually happen

Comment: I have checked that I have valid addresses. Is there a way to actually check if the prior write happened?

Comment: Beside the design hierarchy tab, you will find a memory tab. There you can select all memory-like declared signals and show the actual state at the current simulation time (but not in the past).

Comment: Can you post the vhdl code? I had a similar problem, which turned out that the xilinx libraries have a simulation problem (using a bram when the read address is 0 => output is X).

Comment: I looked in the memory tab. The values are changing from their initial value of 0, to U. That doesn't make any sense though. At the time that write enable is high, there is data on the data in line. There is always initialized data on the data in line so this doesn't really make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was caused by one or two writes of uninitialized data all the way in the beginning of the simulation. It created a chain-reaction that didn't show up until later because the values read in the beginning were coincidentally correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but in case someone made the same stupid mistake as me, I'll put my case here.

I accidentally initialized the wire of dout to be 0, which doesn't give me an compilation error but when the output lines are not 0s, it will give me X.